# How do I create multiple worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have been searching for a while now for a way to create more than the default, nether, and end worlds to play in.

Example: I want a PvP world, a no-grief world, a grief-allowed world, etc.
Is this possible by any way? I want all worlds to be active at the same time ie. players can be playing on all worlds at the same time.

I would also like to be able to make portals to the world ie. go in them and you warp to the world.

Is this possible by any way? Please don't post such complicated answers as I am not too much of an expert with Bukkit.

Is there any plugin that can support this.

If you have to know, I am using GroupManager for permissions.

Comment: [Mystcraft?](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/918541-147-mystcraft-0100/)

Comment: I've actually seen this on one server (and I rarely play Multiplayer) on Redstone Development Foundation. I KNOW there is a way to have multiple worlds. I just dont know how the hell it's done, but you got my confirmation :D

Comment: @fredley Um, I'm running a server.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [Multiverse](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/edit-misc-tp-fun-multiverse-2-3-world-management-bukkitdev.3707/):

- Create multiple worlds of different types, seeds and with Custom Generators
- Create portals to let users go between other portals, worlds, or locations
- PermissionsBukkit support (Anything that implements the superperms api - GroupManager does I think)
- iConomy, BOSEconomy, RealEcon, Essentials Econ and Item economy support!
- Show which users are in what worlds
- Create portals to let users go between worlds
- Control who can enter worlds/portals with permissions!

Comment: Well that was quick.... I'll go check this.

Comment: Do I download all 'Core downloads, Portals Downloads, NetherPortals Downloads, and SignPortals Downloads'?

Comment: It depends what features you want. Sounds like you at least want Portals.

Comment: Ok...... Kinda confusing but whatever xD

Comment: The rational is explained [here](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki/Plugins-of-Multiverse-2).

Comment: If you're just looking for multiple worlds and portals to jump between, you just need the Core and Portals. (Inventories is nice to keep your Creative toys out of your Survival worlds, but you didn't mention that in the question)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Multiverse is [My Worlds](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/my-worlds/). I've always found it to be more stable and less lagy. Currently doesn't support 1.5.* but only because BKCommonLib is being slack at updating. I would suggest using Multiverse until BKCommonLib updates and then switch.